# Cannot read error angularjs factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to read a particular data in a distant js (available with ajax calling), so i call a factory in my controller :

```
app.controller('ParamsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'DistantFactory', function($scope, $http, DistantFactory) {


    $scope.dataD = DistantFactory.getDistant();
}]);
```

My factory :

```
app.factory('DistantFactory', function($http, $q) {

    var factory = {
        distant : false,
        getDistant : function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({method: 'GET', url: urlDataDistant, cache: false, timeout: 1500}).
                success(function(data, status) {

                    /* define data */
                    factory.distant = paramsField.params[0].data.date;
                    deferred.resolve(factory.distant);


                }).error(function(data, statuts) {
                    deferred.reject('ERROR');
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }

    // return
    return factory;
});
```

I have this error :

```
Cannot read property 'getDistant' of undefined
```

distant js :

```
var paramsField = {
    "params" : [
        {
            "data" : {
                "date" : "2014-05-03"
            }
        }
     ]
}
```

Comment: You have more parameters than you've described injecting - `app.controller('ParamsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'DistantFactory', function($scope, $http, --->$timeout<---, DistantFactory)` - $timeout is injected with the DistantFactory service.

Comment: Oops, it's an error when i put my code here

Comment: well, as you can see from here, http://plnkr.co/edit/f43y4JRVZs5kqwjdFKDp , the code you posted doesn't throw an error that getDistant is undefined.